# Put each character in a string into its own string - java

Tags: java

I have a string and I want to have that string get split up so that each individual character is in its own string. The string will vary in length as it is user inputted. Thanks in advance

Comment: I bet you don't want to create a new string for each character. Do you want a character array instead? What have you tried?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet as I am not sure what I need to do, but the character array sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = /*Your String here*/;
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
String[] strArray = new String[charArray.length];
String strChars = "";
for (Character c : charArray){
   int i=0;
   strChars = c.toString();
   strArray[i] = strChars;
   System.out.println(strChars);
   i++;
}
System.out.println(strArray.length);
```

Comment: No. The OP wanted each char as its own string :P

Comment: I dont mind if each char isnt in its own string, as long as I can change each character individually.

Comment: @AlexA use StringBuffer then

Comment: Ok if I use the above code how do I access each individual char?

Comment: Info about [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want an array of strings from a string you can try this

```
String[] chars = myString.split("");
```